# Pass a model from a view to form's inner Meta class

Tags: python, django

I want to pass a specific model from my view to my form's inner Meta class:

view:

```
@login_required
def product_create_view(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        create_product_form = CreateProductForm(request.POST, request=request, model=model)
        if create_product_form.is_valid():
            create_product_form.save()
    else:
        create_product_form = CreateProductForm(request=request, model=model)
    return render(request, 'products/product_create.html', {'form': create_product_form})
```

form:

```
class CreateProductForm(ModelForm):

    class Meta:
        model = CreateProductForm.model
        fields = (
            'title',
            'description',
            'price',
            'stock',
            'category'
        )

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        self.request = kwargs.pop('request')
        self.model = kwargs.pop('model')
        super().__init__(*args, **kwargs)
```

Is that possible?

Comment: This doesn't make sense. Why do you want to do this?

Comment: @DanielRoseman see my other question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58184974/serving-a-different-modelform-based-on-selected-category

Comment: Why aren't you using a [`modelform_factory`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/topics/forms/modelforms/#modelform-factory-function)? `modelform_factory(model, exclude=('id',))` will create a model form class for the model class `model` just excluding the id field.

Comment: @dirkgroten how do you validate fields via modelform_factory? Like `def clean_category(...)`?

Comment: You didn't say you had any customised validation...

Comment: `modelform_factory(model, form=BaseForm, exclude=('id',))`. If the `BaseForm` does not have a `Meta`, the factory will build the `Meta` for you. So I think you can make `BaseForm` inherit from `ModelForm` without giving it a `Meta` class and that way define any methods you want.

Answer (score 0):

This won't work, as the form with its fields is created when the file is loaded. You can probably move the class definition into the function and define it dynamically.

```
@login_required
def product_create_view(request):

    class CreateProductForm(ModelForm):
        class Meta:
            model = model
            fields = (
                'title',
                'description',
                'price',
                'stock',
                'category'
            )

    if request.method == 'POST':
        create_product_form = CreateProductForm(request.POST, request=request)
        if create_product_form.is_valid():
            create_product_form.save()
    else:
        create_product_form = CreateProductForm(request=request)
    return render(request, 'products/product_create.html', {'form': create_product_form})
```

I haven't tried it though.